# Work Done While Hiking Through Elevation Field (Hills)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-fields

I want to calculate (for optimal path purposes) work done while hiking through hills. Hill heights would be in a $E(x,y)$, a scalar for a point in a flat surface $x,y$. I would also like to factor in work done even walking horizontally in flat surface.

How can I use work calculation / line integrals for this? Can I turn $E$ and friction into an $\vec{F}$ perhaps where for every $z>0$ where $E(x,y)>0$ I have a little up pointing vector, and some friction force in $x,y$ directions, so the vector field looks like

$$
\vec{F} = f i + f j + g k
$$

where $f$ is a constant values related to friction and $g$ related to gravity (walking up, where $g$ would be picked as much larger than $f$, I want walking uphill to cost much more than walking horizontally).

Then for any path represented by parametrized curve $r(t)$ through this field I could compute $W = \int \vec{F} dr$.

Does this make sense, especially for friction? Maybe  I should always pick a constant length vector in the direction of the path itself that represents work done whereever you walk horizontally..?

Also a potential problem, if a path goes up and down a hill, returning to where it started, would this  result in zero work done (this would not be useful for me)?

Thanks,

Comment: Friction as a vector will not just depend on position but on velocity, generally being oriented toward the negative of velocity. Besides that you can make up a model along these lines, though strict energy balance is not how a real human hiking perceives difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking I would keep velocity constant, so only distance contributes to energy expanded, more vertically than horizontally.

Comment: What do you think on uphill + downhill problem? If I have gravity pointing downwards, would going up and down cancel work?

Comment: How does a hiker perceive difficulty? Imagine uniform terrain, walking flat is preferred over going uphill (granted it doesnt make path much longer), isn't it?

Comment: For example, a hiker going up and then down spends more energy than a hiker going the same distance on flat ground. In fact, a large enough downhill slope is harder than flat ground on foot because you have to constantly lose momentum to avoid falling. I guess one way you could model this would be to introduce a dependence of the friction on the local slope.

Comment: Also this question as an optimization problem doesn't really make sense if you keep velocity constant (since then there is only one path). It does make sense if you keep speed constant, but in that case the velocity dependence of friction still appears.

Comment: "For example, a hiker going up and then down spends more energy than a hiker going the same distance on flat ground." That's exactly what I am saying. Also another problem is with work / line integral, using the usual formula, up and down will neutralize eachother. I need an integral that punishes heights basically more than horizontal movement. Not sure how to get there.

Comment: Opt will make sense if energy expanded depends on c1*horizontal distance+c2*vertical distance where c2 >> c1. BTW u used speed and velocity, aren't they the same thing? :)

Comment: Speed is a number, velocity is a vector.

Comment: I just realized maybe all I need is length of curve calculation - as in $L = \int _{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{d y}{d x} \right)^2} d x $ for 2D, find the x,y version of this, seperately find z component, multiply with different weights, sum.

Comment: A problem with that model is that it doesn't take into account that it's a lot harder to go up a sheer cliff than to go, say, $\sqrt{2}$ times as far at a 45 degree upward angle, which is itself a lot harder than going $\sqrt{5}$ times as far at a 30 degree upward angle.

Comment: That's fine. I think it'll be good enough for what Im trying to do.

Comment: (Silly mistake, that $\sqrt{5}$ is just $2$, but presumably you see the point.) Glad my mildly pedantic brainstorming got you to something satisfactory.